# Bootstrap - flexible for every screen size or device

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Today I have one questions regarding to Bootstrap on different screen size or devices.

Example now I want to create a website which suitable for desktop, laptop, mobile and tablet.

Inside the HTML class, should I set the container become `fluid-container`?

Or I need to apply `.col-lg` `col-sm` `col-xs`?

Because I wish my website can display perfectly on any devices and screen size.

Thank you and sorry if this question is duplicated.

Because I fail to search any article related regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using Bootstrap 3, don't use fluid-container, it's been replaced by container. Just do something like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">50%</div><div class="col-md-6">50%</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3">25%</div><div class="col-md-3">25%</div><div class="col-md-3">25%</div><div class="col-md-3">25%</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">33%</div><div class="col-md-4">33%</div><div class="col-md-4">33%</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: does col-md supports different screen size?